# asp.net mvc 3 areas and url routing configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have problem with create ulr routing for asp.net mvc3 application.

My project has this structure :

- Areas

  - EmployeeReport

    - Controllers

      - Report
    - Views

      - Report

        - List
        - ....
- Controllers

  - Login
- Viwes

  - Login

    - ...

EmployeeReportAreaRegistration.cs :

```
public class EmployeeReportAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "EmployeeReport";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        var routes = context.Routes;

        routes.MapRoute(null, "vykazy/vykazy-zamestnance", new { Area = "EmployeeReport", controller = "Report", action = "List" });

    }
}
```

Global.asax :

```
        routes.MapRoute(null, "prihlasit", new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" });

        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Default", action = "Welcome", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

```
When i try load "http://localhost/app_name/vykazy/vykazy-zamestnance
i get this exception :

The view 'List' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Report/List.aspx
~/Views/Report/List.ascx
~/Views/Shared/List.aspx
~/Views/Shared/List.ascx
~/Views/Report/List.cshtml
~/Views/Report/List.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/List.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/List.vbhtml
```

Well, where I do mistake ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revised answer:

Adding to Context.Routes directly means it loses any information about Areas.

Either use AreaRegistration.MapRoute (which is overriden to put in the Area information).

```
context.MapRoute(...);
```

Or put the area in the DataTokens parameter (not the defaults parameter as you have done here)

```
context.Routes.MapRoute("", "url", new {...}, null, new {area = this.AreaName});
```

Comment: Hmm, i have AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() on top of Application_Start() function in global.asax

Comment: Yes, i have folder EmployeeReportArea under Areas folder. Fixed in first comment.

Comment: My mistake, the fact that it was searching for the view meant that it found the route.

Try using http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx and see if this helps.

Comment: I have looked at my own code, and I do not specify "area" in my route registration... try removing that property.

Comment: Yes, Routing debbuger have installed and he says all is ok :
True vykazy/vykazy-zamestnance Area = EmployeeReport, controller = Report, action = Lis (null) (null)

Comment: And when I try debbug application, controller catch request correctly

Comment: Do not add directly to Context.Routes.
Use overriden MapRoute function, that handles Area for you.

Comment: I have revised my answer to match :)

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure for your area should look like so:

- Areas

  - EmployeeReport

    - Controllers
    - Views

Comment: Yes, sorry it was mistake while I posting question. Fixed